# Maven OSGi integration/system test

Tags: testing, osgi, integration

I want maven to test if a built OSGi bundle could be installed and started successfully into an all-the-time running OSGi framework (Equinox).

Building a valid OSGIi bundle using maven is already solved. Now, i want to make the described integration/system test. Investigations gave me the following approaches:

- autodeploy via Maven
- start + install of OSGi bundle via Felix File Install
- get results of bundle start via felix web console JSON API or..how easier?
- parse the result via shell-script and return result to maven. then, maven should eventually say "BUILD FAILED"

or

- Using JUnit4OSGI
- Using Pax Exam

What would you recommend and why?

Regards
Doe

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Pax Exam, and yes I'm biased ;) 
But afaik this one actually fits all your needs as you said, beeing run from maven etc. 
As you already seem to be aware of Pax Exam I'd suggest visit the web-page for it, get in contact with the people developing and using it at the corresponding mailinglist etc..

Comment: But isn't Pax Exam made for Unit-testing? I only want to know if the bundle could be started correctly.

Comment: Yes - you can/should use the unit test (PaxExam) to test f the bundle could be started correctly.

Comment: Pax Exam is made for Integration tests, not unit tests ... it uses unit tests for those. Unit tests should test the correct function of the method, with Pax Exam you can verify if your Bundles are A) deployed Correctly, B) the services are available and C) if your wiring for i) Bundles ii) Services is done correctly

Comment: So, Pax Exam uses JUnit (intended to run unit tests) to run integration tests, right? And this can be done without using JUnit4OSGI, right?

Is it possible to run the integration test in an OSGI-Framework that runs all the time, irrespective of maven builds which invoke Pax Exam?

Comment: yep, take a look at the documentation.